# Nuxt Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers when mutating from plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Firebase alongside a Nuxt project, in the following plugin, I call `onAuthStateChanged` to check if the user is already logged in, if he is I set the user state and redirect him to the dashboard like so:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default ({ store, redirect }) => {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    const config = {
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDFS8Wk6B7ontvZeargY3z7k0u92EJvlN0',
      authDomain: 'jammer-bd4bc.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://jammer-bd4bc.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'jammer-bd4bc',
      storageBucket: 'jammer-bd4bc.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '156254683024'
    }

    firebase.initializeApp(config)
  }

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      store.commit('auth/setUser', user)
      redirect('/dashboard')
    } else {
      redirect('/')
    }
  })
}
```

The plugin is referenced in my `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/firebase'
],
```

But the following error appear when we reach the store commit:

> Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

As if I was mutating the state directly in the plugin (when as you can see I am not).

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Its because you are comming firebase user object to your vuex store. And it later can be changed by firestore itself. So the solution is to clone it before commiting into vuex

Comment: Using a spread operator or an Assign to clone the object does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: @Christopher that wont work on nested object. And i suppose user is a nested object. Try json.parse(json.stringify(user))

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are mutating the store.

`commit()` fires a mutation.

`dispatch()` fires an action

So the easy workaround is to use `dispatch('auth/setUser')` which is a very simple `action` that calls the `commit('auth/setUser')`

Comment: This makes sense, but applying it gives the same error

Comment: Then @Aldarund is on the better track